# Lapply in a nested list in R

Tags: r, try-catch, lapply, nested-lists, do.call

I'm trying to apply a function to a nested list. I have the following lists:

```
lista_a <- list("PEC", "45", "1991")
lista_b <- list("PL", "4580", "1990")
lista_c <- list("PL", "200", "1980")
```

Which are nested in the following list:

```
lista_final <- list(lista_a, lista_b, lista_c)
```

I want to apply the following function (which uses the function `cham_votes` from `congressbr` package):

```
funcao <- function(x){ tryCatch(do.call(cham_votes, x), error=function(e){NA})}
```

To each element of `lista_final`. I am trying to use do.call because `cham_votes` has three inputs (type, number and year) and I want to use them all at the same time, therefore I needed a list.

Do you have any idea how can I apply this function to all elements of `lista_final` at once? The final result should be a list of dataframes.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I get: "Package ‘congressbr’ was removed from the CRAN repository." when attempting to find that package. If you have a package that is not (currently) in CRAN then you need to say where it is and what dependencies it might have.

Comment: Sorry, next time I'll pay attention on this. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score -1):

The function `cham_votes()` expects the last two arguments to be integers. So, you have to convert them first as follows:

```
listafinal <- lapply(listafinal, function(x) c(x[1], lapply(x[2:3], as.integer)))
```

You need then to simply use `lapply`.

```
lapply(lista_final, funcao)
```

This will return a list of elements each of which  is of the same type as the return value of your function `funcao()` which is either `NA` or a tibble of classes `tbl`, `tbl_df`, and `dataframe`

Comment: The proposed code would have expected an argument to be a list. So a single lapply should have been enough.

Comment: Thanks for your help!